# CombineはなぜiOS13以上が必要なのでしょうか？

Tags: swift, ios, combine

[Combine | Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine)

CombineはなぜiOS13以上が必要なのでしょうか？

`RxSwift`で似たようなことはできているはずですので、Swiftのバージョンに依存するのであれば納得感があるのですが（新しい言語機能や内部的なライブラリを組み込むといったイメージで）、一体iOS13のどのような機能に依存しているのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

ドキュメントのトップに

> Framework
>
> Combine

と書かれているので、`Combine`は`Framework`で提供されていて、そのフレームワークが標準で組み込まれているのが、ページの右にある各OSバージョンからなのではないでしょうか。